# Get connected inputs and outputs?

Tags: web-audio-api

Does a WebAudio node have access to other nodes connected to it (either as inputs or outputs)?

For example, I have a gain node and a buffer source node. The buffer source node is wired to the gain node and the gain node is connected to the final destination:

```
var gainNode = ac.createGainNode(); // gain node
ac.createBufferSource().connect(gainNode); // source
gainNode.connect(ac.destination);
```

Given only a reference to the gain node, can I get a reference to the source node? And vice versa.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nope. I'm not totally sure why, though. Seems like that would make a few things quite a bit easier.

EDIT:

If you're feeling adventurous, you could maybe try something crazy like this:

```
AudioNode.prototype.connect = (function(){
  var func = AudioNode.prototype.connect;
  return function(){
   ( this.outputs || ( this.outputs = [] ) ).push(arguments[0]);
   return func.apply(this, arguments);
  }
}());
```

Which would give connected `AudioNodes` an `output` array of their output nodes. You'd also have to override `AudioNode.prototype.disconnect` in a similar way to remove them from the array.

This is probably a *terrible* idea, but might work out for you depending on what you need to do.

Comment: Well, OK :) Thanks, Kevin!

Comment: No, it doesn't - but the reason is if we offered graph introspection on the nodes like this, we wouldn't be able to garbage-collection node subgraphs that were done playing (because you could walk back to the nodes from the destination, and you could "see" them disappear - which means you could observe garbage collection in action, which is a definite JS no-no).

Comment: You can do the connect() override you suggest above, because it's only one-way (the main problem is introspection on what is connected TO a node's input, not what outputs they're connected to); but you'll still need to be quite careful not to affect the object lifetimes.